# Different headers for odd and even pages

Tags: header-footer, double-sided

Please help me to design pages with a different title on odd and even pages:

I mean I would like to have for example

- name of author on odd pages.
- name of article on even pages.

How can I do it?

Many thanks,

Comment: with "different title" do you mean different header? If yes, you should take a look at the `fancyhdr` package

Answer (score 10):

This request only seems viable in the context of headers. As such, here's a [`fancyhdr`](http://ctan.org/pkg/fancyhdr) implementation using a standard document class (`article`):

[image]

```
\documentclass[twoside]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}% http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum
\usepackage{fancyhdr}% http://ctan.org/pkg/fancyhdr
\fancypagestyle{mypagestyle}{%
  \fancyhf{}% Clear header/footer
  \fancyhead[OC]{An Author}% Author on Odd page, Centred
  \fancyhead[EC]{A title}% Title on Even page, Centred
  \fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}%
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{.4pt}% Header rule of .4pt
}
\pagestyle{mypagestyle}
\title{A title}
\author{An Author}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\section{A section}\lipsum[1-20]
\end{document}
```

`twoside` is required to allow `O`dd and `E`ven side varying page styles, but you most likely already use this class option.

Since the `\maketitle` macro is "self-destructing" and thereby erases `\@author` and `\@title`, you need to either make a copy of it into a different macro, or write the author and title in the respective headers manually.

Comment: It also works with footers