# Treating odd and even numbered pages differently?

Tags: header-footer

I was wondering how to treat odd and even numbered pages differently, for example I want the page number appear on the upper right corner of the page on *odd pages* while upper left corner of the page on *even pages*. How can I accomplish this? Many thanks in advance

Comment: Check this out: [Different headers for odd and even pages](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/64195/5764)

Comment: There are many ways to achieve this, like using `fancyhdr`, or using the in built commands of the KOMA class etc. It depends largely on the document class that you are using

Comment: Just don't specify a [oneside] document class.

Comment: @JohnKormylo - Some document classes, incl. `article` and `report`, set the option `oneside` by default. For such classes, it's necessary to specify `twoside` explicitly in order to get the page number placement to depend on whether the page number is even or odd.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you're using the `article` or `report` document class, or a class that's based on one of these classes, you may achieve your objective, which I'll paraphrase as

> I want the page number to appear in the upper right corner of the page on *odd-numbered pages* but in the upper left corner of the page on *even-numbered pages*

by specifying the document class option `twoside` explicitly and by inserting the instruction

```
\pagestyle{myheadings}
```

in the preamble.

A full MWE (minimum working example):

```
\documentclass[twoside]{article} % or: "report"
\pagestyle{myheadings}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-20]
\end{document}
```

There are other, far more general, ways of determining what goes in the header and footer lines of a page. You may want to study the user guide of the `fancyhdr` package for some of the possibilities. Some document classes, such as the `memoir` class and the KOMA-Script family of document classes, provide further possibilities in this regard.